# Spring Security on Rest services

Tags: spring, spring-security, taglib

I have implmented a server backend for a mobile client using Spring MVC,Restful webservices. I want to secure the app with spring security. I have put a custom login.jsp to handle the login  as follows.

```
<body onload='document.f.j_username.focus();'>
<h3>Login with Username and Password (Custom Page)</h3>

<c:if test="${not empty error}">
    <div class="errorblock">
        Your login attempt was not successful, try again.<br /> Caused :
        ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
    </div>
</c:if>

<form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />"
    method='POST'>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='j_password' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                value="submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input name="reset" type="reset" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

my web.xml is as follows.

```
<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

spring-security-context.xml is as follws.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">


<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/getHierarchy" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/getHierarchy"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

But I get a warning on eclipse

> The tag handler class for "c:if" (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag) was not found on the Java Build Path

And get a not found error on j_spring_security_check when I submit the form. I have included jstl1.2 in the classpath. Why do I get a tag handler not found warning even if I have included the taglib?

Comment: Have you posted the COMPLETE `login.jsp` or did you skipped the header?

Comment: yeah I skipped the header...There are only few style tags in it.Nothing more. Taglib declaration is as follows.
`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>`

Comment: You wrote: `I have included jstl1.2 in the classpath.` In which folder is it included exactly? For example `\myProject\libs` or `\myProject\webapp\WEB-INF\lib`?

Comment: it is in \myProject\webapp\WEB-INF\lib folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why do I get a tag handler not found warning even if I have included the taglib?**
The jars in an Eclipse Dynamic Web Project that should be deployed to the server must be located in the `\myProject\WebContent\WEB-INF\libs` *(not in \myProject\webapp\WEB-INF\lib)*

In a Eclipse Dynamic Web Project the jars in this folder will be automaticly attached to your build path, you must not add them manually.

---

**And get a not found error on j_spring_security_check when I submit the form:**

Check that you have the login page mapped to the url `/login` *you can test it simply by enter the url in your broswer*

---

**Additional hint**

One other thing that is may not so optimal is this statement

```
<form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />"
   method='POST'>
```

Try to write it in this way:

```
<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' var='loginUrl'/>
<form name='f' action="${loginUrl}" method='POST'>
```

This avoid this nasty weaving of the two tags. Maybe the problem is just that the eclipse editor is a bit confused.

---

[image: The Java Build Path should look like the image at the end of course you will have some more libs]

Comment: In my development project, jars are in `\myProject\WebContent\WEB-INF\libs`and still the problem exists. But when I change the http tag in the security-context file as follows,
`<http auto-config="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/getHierarchy" access="ROLE_USER" />
  <http-basic/>
  
 </http>`
it works fine. I have the problem with the tag libraries I guess.

Comment: I have added an other point, but this is just a hint, it should not be related to your not found problem.